# flutter_uploader can somebody explain a little more (flutter newbie)

Tags: php, flutter

I have searched around and found a few article/results about basics of the **flutter_uploader** functions, but am stumped to work out how to do the server-side bit and also getting the result from server in a decodable format.
I have created PHP scripts in the past for Multipart form data upload, but this time it seems different.

I have a camera image file saved locally in the app document directory, all good as it can be loaded and displayed in a widget.
Then I try and upload via the flutter_uploader, with code:

```
_taskId = await _uploaderService.enqueue(
        MultipartFormDataUpload(
          url: '_url to server PHP file',
          files: [FileItem(path: 'full path to locally stored image', field: "userfile")],
          method: UploadMethod.POST,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
          },
          data: { "groupId": "87878" }
          tag: filename,
        ),
      );
      _uploaderService.result.listen((result) {
        if (result.statusCode == 200 && result.response != null) {
          dynamic body = jsonDecode(result.response!);
          print(body);
          _uploaderService.clearUploads();
        }
      }, onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
        _taskId = null;
        _uploaderService.clearUploads();
      });
```

So, the server PHP script gets called but I am not getting the **$_POST['groupId']**, I can add variables to the URL and get them via **$_GET** in the PHP, but that feels odd when there seems to be support for a **data** object in the post block.

I am trying to repurpose my previous PHP script, but am struggling getting the file & variables read plus working out how to return a JSON string and decoding that back in the flutter uploader listener stream.

In the PHP I have tried:

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer($request_body);
```

but get error when trying to save the file request body into server-side file path:

```
file_put_contents($photofile, $request_body)
```

I also tried to see if the **$_FILES** object exists by returning the **$_FILES["userfile"]["temp_name"]**, but it seems to be empty when trying:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $photofile)
```

btw: when I say **returning info**, the return data does show up in the VSCode debug window, but I have not worked out how to get the same data to come through to the **_uploaderService.result.listen((result) ....** handler.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're apparently sending `multipart/form-data`, but you're overriding the Content-Type to be `application/json`, so the server can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs that fixed the content-type, got it all working now, I ended up getting all POST variables and used the $_FILES object to handle the image.